# Iterate table HTML

Tags: html, html-table, display

I want to iterate through tbodies into table and compare the content of each row1 with 'B'.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>row1</th><td>A</td></tr>
        <tr><th>row2</th><td>A</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>row1</th><td>B</td></tr>
        <tr><th>row2</th><td>B</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>row1</th><td>C</td></tr>
        <tr><th>row2</th><td>C</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When the tbody with row1 content 'B' is found, I want it to disappear with (display:none).

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself?

Comment: Iterate with what? What programming language do you use? You can use jQuery and its selectors but there is no iteration involved.

Comment: Maybe iterating is not the correct term for describing what I want. I want to go throw each <tbody> of the table checking the content of the first row and comparing it with a value, when the comparation is succesful I want that <tbody> to disappear, maybe using display:none.

Comment: I want to do it with javascript

Answer (score 1):

```
Var table = document.getElementByName('table').children;

For(b = 1 ; b < table.length() ; b++)
{
       Var cells = table[b].children;
       for(c = 1 ; c < cells.length() ; c++)
       {
               If(cells[c].childNodes[0].innerHtml == 'row1')
              {
                     If((cells[c].childNodes[1].innerHtml == 'B')
                     Console.log("jackpot");
               }
       }
}
```

Comment: Most welcome, btw, try it with ids on you table, so you can use getElementById instead of getElementByName, at least there will be much less probability for things to go wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your help. At the end I asked the question in another post because I think that I haven't been clear enough on this. I finally solved the problem, check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962221/html-finding-and-stop-displaying-table-child

Comment: You're welcome, my fault was the length attribute, as I wrote it as a method :) . Have been working with java too much lately I'm starting mix things up.

Comment: Instead of innerHtml you have to use innerHTML ;-)

Comment: Yup, I'm on my mobile, I'll delete the app and go back to desktop I guess :)