# HTML finding and stop displaying table child

Tags: javascript, html, children

I've done this:

```
<table id="tabla">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>row1</th><td>w</td></tr>
        <tr><th>row2</th><td>x</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>row1</th><td>y</td></tr>
        <tr><th>row2</th><td>z</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function iterate() {
        var table = document.getElementById("tabla").children;
        for (b=0; b<table.length(); b++) {
            var cells = table[b].children;
            if(cells[0].innerHtml == "row1") {
                if(cells[1].innerHtml == "w") {
                    table[b].style.display="none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My intention is to find all children of the table that satisfy a condition and to stop displaying them.

My code is not working, I do not know why.

Does anyone know?

Comment: table.length() is not a function. remove the brackets and use `table.length` instead

Comment: also, call your function with `iterate()`.

Comment: and why do you have multiple `tbody` elements?

Comment: The reason of having more than one tbody is that I want to group some rows to make them work as one row. Maybe there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The children of your `table` element are `tbody`
2. There is no `length()` function, it's an attribute (just use `length`)
3. There is no `innerHtml`, you should use `innerHTML`
4. The `cells[0]` you refer to is actually the row (and not the cell) so it's innerHTML == `<th>row1</th><td>w</td>`

Here is the fix to your code:

```js
function iterate() {
  var table = document.getElementById("tabla").children;
  for (b=0; b<table.length; b++) {
    var rows = table[b].children;
    for (r=0; r<rows.length;r++) {
      var cells = rows[r].children
      if (cells[0].innerHTML == "row1") {
        if (cells[1].innerHTML == "w") {
          table[b].style.display="none";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

iterate();
```

```html
<table id="tabla">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>row1</th><td>w</td></tr>
        <tr><th>row2</th><td>x</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>row1</th><td>y</td></tr>
        <tr><th>row2</th><td>z</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have more than one tbody because I want to group some rows to make them work as one. How can I group rows without using tbody?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I think that is not working correctly.

Comment: It works well for the first tbody, but if I want to stop displaying the second tbody (row1:y) doesn't work.

Comment: table.length is 2, but that for loop only does one iteration... I can't understand why.

Comment: But you check if the innerHTML == w, and it's not the case in the second tbody.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function iterate() {
        var table = document.getElementById("tabla").children;
      
        for (b=0; b<table.length; b++) {
            var cells = table[b].children;
          
            if(cells[0].children[0].innerHTML == "row1") {
                if(cells[0].children[1].innerHTML == "w") {
                    table[b].style.display="none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
iterate();
```

```css
*{
background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<table id="tabla">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>row1</th><td>w</td></tr>
        <tr><th>row2</th><td>x</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>row1</th><td>y</td></tr>
        <tr><th>row2</th><td>z</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tabla").children;
    for (b=0; b<table.length; b++) {
        var rows = table[b].children;
        var cells = rows[0].children;
        if (cells[0].innerHTML == "row1") {
            if (cells[1].innerHTML != "x") {
              table[b].style.display="none";
            } else {
                table[b].style.display="block";
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't iterate through all elements of each tbody because I am only interested in the first element.